# Convert string to integer and multiply two integers

Tags: php, string, int, woocommerce

I have a big time trying to either convert a string into a integer or multiply two integers. I can't convert the string into integer because it's resulting me into a boolean (when I'm using var_dump). I can convert the other integer in string, but I'm unable to multiply it.

I have this:

```
    <? $fees=$commerce->cart->get_total(); 
    $payfee = str_replace('&nbsp;&euro;', '', $fees);
    $payfee = str_replace(',','', $payfee);  //this is the string
    $fee = 0.025;
    $paypal = $payfee * $fee;  //this thing is not working

    ?>
```

I tried converting the payfee in integer, but still can't make it work. I did something like this before and worked well, but not this time.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S Thank you to the whole stackoverflow.com community which helped me many times before.

Comment: Is there no method to get the total as pure number, without formatting? If so: madness!

Comment: @deceze Any idea ? I've done something like this before and worked without issues. Whay do I need to format ? I tried formating, but maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Comment: I don't know. What cart system is that? If it's some third-party system, read the documentation on how you can get the raw numbers. Otherwise we'd need to see the exact data you're working with.

Comment: @deceze From the `cart->get_total()` part and a google search, my *guess* is that it's "WooCommerce".

Comment: @deceze it's woocommerce, just modified a bit the code here so nobody starts to troll why i'm trying to modify the source. Dumping the $fees is output something like "5,600 €", so I've used str_replace to remove the comma and euro sign. After str_replace, I'm getting 5600. Now, I want to multiply those 5600 to 0.025, in order to get the fee ($paypal).

Comment: @demlasjr My previous reply on Registered User counts - however - looking at the WooCommerce API, I think what you want is `$paypal = $commerce->cart->total * 0.025`, [as the `$total` value in their class is a `float` and not a string](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#$total)

Comment: In addition to @h2o's advice, it would seem to me that this should be integrated in one of the payment processor classes, and may already be integrated in the Paypal component. I have not looked deeper into it to give any more details.

Comment: @deceze: All I want is to add a fee to the paypal payments (if the people choose to pay via paypal). I got it works in paypal, but can't make it show in the billing page and there is no plugin or component which can do that sadly. There are many people/clients trying to find such a component for woocommerce (paypal payment with fees).

Comment: @h2ooooooo tried directly and the var_dump is giving me a "NULL"

Comment: here is the whole php. Lines 177 - 184 are the ones I'm trying to do here.  http://pastebin.com/R0DKF9TR

Comment: @demlasjr Check my latest answer - it should answer your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> OP is running WooCommerce, and his `$commerce->cart->get_total();`
>   function responds output such as `<span class="amount">560&nbsp;&euro;</span>` (560 €)
>   and he's asking how to convert this to a number so he can get a fee
>   (2.5 %) from the amount.

First of all, the problem here is that the `get_total()` function responds with a string.

The correct way to fix this string would be a simple example such as

```
<?php
    $totalAmountString = $commerce->cart->get_total(); //<span class="amount">560&nbsp;&euro;</span>
    $totalAmountString = strip_tags($totalAmountString); //get rid of the span - we're left with "560&nbsp;&euro;"
    $totalAmountString = str_replace(array("&nbsp;&euro;", ","), "", $totalAmountString);
    $totalAmountFloat = (float)$totalAmountString;
    $fee = 0.025;
    $feeForThisAmount = $totalAmountFloat * $fee;
    var_dump($feeForThisAmount);

    $totalAmountWithFee = $totalAmountFloat + $feeForThisAmount;
    var_dump($totalAmountWithFee);
?>
```

However, according to the [Woo Commerce API Documentation](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html#%24total) you should be able to use `$commerce->cart->total` to get a float of the number, so a solution that *might* also work (again, I know nothing about WooCommerce), would be the following:

```
<?php
    $totalAmountFloat = $commerce->cart->total;
    $fee = 0.025;
    $feeForThisAmount = $totalAmountFloat * $fee;
    var_dump($feeForThisAmount);

    $totalAmountWithFee = $totalAmountFloat + $feeForThisAmount;
    var_dump($totalAmountWithFee);
?>
```

***Edit***

According to your latest data dump, the problem is that you're using

```
$paypal_fees=$woocommerce->cart->get_total() * 0.025;
```

where you should be using

```
$paypal_fees=$woocommerce->cart->total * 0.025;
```

as `->get_total()` receives a string, and `->total` receives a float.

Comment: Best answer ever received on this website ! however, doing the Edit part, I'm still getting a NULL, doing the first part, the var_dump($feeForThisAmount); gives me float(14), which is correct ! Guess I need to send you a truck full of beer.

Comment: @demlasjr Thanks for the nice words. What do you get if you `var_dump($woocommerce->cart->total)`? Also `NULL`?

Comment: You're welcome. var_dump($woocommerce->cart->total) gives string(6) "560.00"      //////////
                                     
Looks like 
$paypal_fees=$woocommerce->cart->total * 0.025; gives me float(14). Before gave me NULL, probably I made an mistake there. Sorry about that                   
//////////
 
However, the first option works perfectly

Comment: That's because, as the `var_dump` proves, it's not a float, but rather a string (even though the documentation says differently). So you should be able to use `$paypal_fees=(float)$woocommerce->cart->total * 0.025;`

Comment: I think I made a mistake before, because tried again now and works perfectly in both ways ! You helped me a lot with all this ! You should start doing the missing plugins for woocommerce and post them in woocommerce market and codecanyon. People and I would be happy to buy them !

Comment: Has anybody found that this method fails [`$woocommerce->cart->total` always has a value of zero] when the user clicks update cart

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$integer =(int)$string;
```

[LIve example](http://codepad.org/sroEAGCO)

with var_dump() its correct

[image]

[check this link](http://codepad.org/pYJf3Teu)

Comment: Could it be used like `int($string)` just like in C++?

Comment: @MarkGarcia no you can use like this it will cause the `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Comment: I tried this guys and no luck. The result of var_dump ($integer) is boolean(true), which is weird as hell...

Comment: Thanks @RegisteredUser ! Tried that right now and even before, but nothing changed. This is what I'm getting, to have an idea about the input. http://codepad.org/pHKfLgQ5  I started believe the server is trolling me...

Comment: `string(31) "560"` - what? Sounds like there's invisible characters in there (considering the 31 character length). Try `var_dump(urlencode($string));`

Comment: @h2ooooooo doing that I'm getting something like: string(47) "%3Cspan+class%3D%22amount%22%3E560%3C%2Fspan%3E"

Comment: @demlasjr So it's actually in an HTML box (a span that is), and if you look at the source, you'd be able to see it (however it isn't being rendered on the site, as it just outputs the HTML). Try calling `var_dump(strip_tags($string));` to remove the HTML tags first

Comment: @RegisteredUser can't get the $paypal mate. it's not output the result.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Doing that gives string(3) "560", mixing strip_tags with urlencode gives same result as above (the long one). I'm lost with this one :/

Comment: @demlasjr You're already there! This means you can say `$integer = (int)strip_tags($string);` and you'll have your number.

Comment: @h2ooooooo And we have a winner ! I've done this:         $fee = "25";
        $integer2 = (int)$fee;
        $paypal = $integer * ($integer2 / 1000);   and now is working well, the only issue is that the results is a float(14), but still ok. You should post the solution as individual so I can accept it as answer.

Comment: @h2ooooooo also +1 form me id you posted the  separate answer.. for your efforts

Comment: @RegisteredUser Done as requested. With info for google to capture, of course, so if other people search for it, they'd be able to find it.

Comment: @h2ooooooo so you have got +1 from me

Comment: @RegisteredUser +1 from me too. Thank you buddy for your help too.

Answer (score 2):

Use intval() function to covert string to integer

[intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: All I get in var_dump is "int(0)" if I'm doing this :)

Answer (score 2):

Use type casting like

```
$integer = (int)$myString;
```

then you can convert it to an integer,and its become easy to multiply

Comment: how is your answer different from @RegisteredUser

Answer (score 0):

From your elementary school technique based algorithm is posted [here](https://os-concept.blogspot.com/2018/12/multiply-two-integers-represented-by.html) . You need not to convert string to integer in this case